# proximity card reader - smartcardio issue

Tags: smartcard, contactless-smartcard

I am developing a Java swing app where I have to read a id card using the hid omnikey 5325
proximity reader using the smartcardio api. (windows xp os)

```
try {
    terminals = factory.terminals().list();
    System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);
    // get the first terminal
    CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);
    terminal.waitForCardPresent(0); 
    Card card = terminal.connect("T=0");                    
    System.out.println("Card present!");            
    System.out.println("card: " + card);        
} catch (CardException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code detects the reader, but when the card is inserted, the 
`terminal.waitForCardPresent(0)` is supposed to return, which it doesnt.

When I use the HID's own workbench, the card is detected, hence there are no issues
with the card or the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting a card terminal from a list using just an index. This is not the most reliable method of choosing a terminal. The reason you get the wrong terminal is that the reader contains both a contact and contactless readers, which are separate readers to the system. So you were waiting for a contact card to be inserted.

Instead it is much better to [choose a card reader by name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CardTerminals.html#getTerminal%28java.lang.String%29). You can get the name by using your `List` of `CardTerminal`s and then printing out the [name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CardTerminal.html#getName%28%29) (or use a diagnostics utility etc., the name is the PCSC determined name for the reader, compiled by your operating system using the reader characteristics and a sequence number).

Comment: No problem, if this solves the issue, the best way to say thanks is hitting the V sign at the left of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.
Changing the line:

CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);
to
CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(1); did the trick.
Guess this array starts from 1 instead of 0.